# Copy row on Sheet 1 to all existing sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I got a excel file with 30 sheets in it all containing the same first row. 
I'm searching for a code/way  that copies the first row on sheet 1 and pastes it on all the existing sheets.

The rows change regularly and through this way I only have to adjust it once.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `.FillAcrossSheets` to do this:

```
Sub CopyToAllSheets()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Sheets.FillAcrossSheets ws.Range("1:1")
End Sub
```

Note that you can specify what you want to copy with an optional type parameter:

- Copy both contents and formatting = `xlFillWithAll`
- Copy contents only = `xlFillWithContents`
- Copy formats only = `xlFillWithFormats`

The default is `xlFillWithAll`. If you want to use one of the other options, do this:

```
' copy contents
Sheets.FillAcrossSheets ws.Range("1:1") xlFillWithContents
```

or

```
' copy formats
Sheets.FillAcrossSheets ws.Range("1:1") xlFillWithFormats
```

In case you don't want to copy to every sheet in your workbook, you can specify a list of target sheets like this:

```
Sub CopyToSpecificSheets()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim targetSheets As Variant

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    ' the sheet we are copying from must be included in the array
    targetSheets = Array(ws.Name, "Sheet2", "Sheet4")
    wb.Sheets(targetSheets).FillAcrossSheets ws.Range("1:1")
End Sub
```

Comment: You can also copy the user selection like so: `Sheets.FillAcrossSheets Selection`

Answer (score 0):

could do a simple way assuming you have the standard 3 sheet set up (Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3)

Do all of the changes in Sheet 1, Then click Sheet 2, Shift + Click Sheet 3.

in Cell A1, type =sheet1!a1

copy it across how ever far you need.

Select Sheet 1 (to remove the grouping)

Now sheet 2 and 3 will have the same top row. This works for as many sheets as excel supports. So clicking sheet2, then shift click sheet 50 will fill out all sheets in the range Sheet2 - sheet 50

Answer (score 0):

Consider something like:

```
Sub qwerty()
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Sheets(1).Range("1:1")
    For n = 2 To Sheets.Count
        r.Copy Sheets(n).Range("A1")
    Next n
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following : Click and hold on "Shift" on your keyboard, then with your mouse click the last sheet. You'll notice that all sheets will be grouped ( Notice the keyword "Group" at the top top of your excel file). Now everything you do on 1 sheet will be applied to all while in group mode.